# Webservice and RPC, when to use them respectively?

Tags: server, client, rpc

I need to implement a C/S structured system. Should I use RPC(like protobuf) or WebService(like SOAP based web service) as the communication infrastructure between the client and server?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many angels dance on the head of a pin?

I prefer using SOAP  calls, especially if I'm using visual studio because creating and consuming them is so easy and reliable.

I like REST calls if my client cannot easily handle SOAP calls and/or I have large volumes of calls or network limitations. The reasoning is that REST calls are harder to code and consume and less reliable when it comes to enforce interface consumption.

I try to balance software development time, reliability, and ease of consumption against scalability.